# Why does the SQL conditional not match "OR" clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know where else to ask. I have this query:

```
SELECT po.* FROM posts po, follows f, user pn
                  WHERE (f.follower_id = #{id}
                    AND f.followed_id = pn.id
                    AND po.user_id = pn.id)
                    OR (po.user_id = #{id})
                  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET #{offset}
```

I get the posts from the followers correctly, but not the posts by the user himself. It seems as if the second part of the `OR` is always ignored.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = #{id}
```

works fine, though.

**EDIT**

I am sorry, I accidentally hit enter before I was done with the text!!

**EDIT 2**

This now seems to work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT po.* FROM users pn
                    INNER JOIN follows f ON f.follower_id = #{id}
                    INNER JOIN posts po ON po.user_id = f.followed_id OR po.user_id = #{id}
                  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET #{offset}
```

Maybe someone can tell me why?

Comment: Error output from MySQL would be helpful, if there is an error.  Otherwise we need to know what the query does, and what you want it to do.  We can't see your monitor, nor can we read your mind.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally hit enter as I was tagging before I was done with the text.

Comment: I'm missing how your "Follows" table is associated to the posts table.  Is there both the "userID" and "postID" in the "follower" table?  What is the key column on the "posts" table if that is the case... "PostID" or is the "followerID" the actual "userID"?

Comment: @DRapp: My `follows` table is an association between two users. So `follower_id` and `followed_id` reference the `users` table. The `posts` table has a column `user_id` which contains the posting user and which I want to use to find all the posts from the users that the given user follows, plus his own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT po.* FROM posts po, follows f, user pn
  WHERE f.follower_id = #{id}
    AND f.followed_id = pn.id
    AND (   po.user_id = pn.id
         OR po.user_id = #{id})
  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET #{offset}
```

The implicit joins were not being considered in the second case.  This is one of the reasons I shy away from implicit joins, instead using explicit `INNER JOIN` clauses.

If this doesn't get the results you are looking for, you might need to consider a `UNION` instead.  Your description is a bit vague and you have not given us your schema, so I can't tell if this query will work or not.

Comment: The above does not work, but a union does. How efficient is a `UNION` if the `LIMIT 10` is done after it?

Comment: What exactly information would you need to tell me why the above does not work either?

Comment: @Andriy: ... what?  One is followeR_id, the other is followeD_id.

Comment: @Scan: The efficiency of the query will depend on several factors.  Use `EXPLAIN` to see the query plan being generated, and make sure no table scans are occurring.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT po.* FROM posts po, follows f, user pn
WHERE f.follower_id = #{id} AND 
      f.followed_id = pn.id AND 
      (po.user_id = pn.id OR po.user_id = #{id})
ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET #{offset}
```

Try this. I reckon the bracket were false.